# MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline into a JS function don't work with $out

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my problem : I would like to make a MongoDB aggregation Pipeline into a JS function and that this aggregation stock its result into a collection.

To make this I have 2 solutions :

Make an insertMany after convert the result of aggregation to an array like this :

```
function myFunction(){
    console.log("Start");
    db.Collection1.insertMany(db.Collection2.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {...}
            },
            {
                $project: {...}
            },
            {
                $group: {...}
            },
            {
                $addFields: {...}
            }
        ]
    ).toArray());
    console.log("End");
}
```

Or make a $out into the aggregation like this :

```
function myFunction(){
    console.log("Start");
    db.Collection2.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {...}
            },
            {
                $project: {...}
            },
            {
                $group: {...}
            },
            {
                $addFields: {...}
            },
            {
                $out: {"collection1"}
            }
        ]
    );
    console.log("End");
}
```

In these 2 solutions the console displays the 2 messages, but in the solution with the $out the aggregation is not executed and i don't know why.

If anyone has a solution I'm interested.

Thank you in advance and sorry in advance for my English which is not very good

Comment: The `$out` operator takes the collection name just as a string. Try `{$out: "collection1"}`

Comment: I actually use the `$out` as you say, I made a mistake in copying, sorry

Comment: Do you get the output of just the aggregate query without $out?

Comment: If i return the result of the aggregate query without the $out and if i call the function, i get the output.